# Simple model and IEnumerable model in one model to view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

How can I use one simple model and one `IEnumerable` model in one model and call in view?

```
public class ModelMix
{
    public Posts PostsObject { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Album> ThreadsObject { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: So what problems are you having?

Answer (score 0):

It is simple: Just use ModelMix in @model of your view!.